# Exactly how are parameters initialized by the arguments passed in the function call in C++?

Tags: c++

In the following code :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void fun(T1 x, T2 y, T3 z){
    // some code
}
int main(){
   T1 a;
   T2 b;
   T3 c;
   fun(a,b,c);
}
```

I wanted to understand, how the parameters(x, y, and z)  in the function "fun" are getting initialized by the arguments(a,b, and c) passed during the function call. Is the copy constructor invoked and then initialization happens like  `T1 x = a; T2 y = b; T3 z = c;`  or something else take place?

Please explain.

Comment: Your parameters are not reference or const reference so a copy of x, y, z will happen.

Comment: Build with optimization disabled. Take a look at the generated assembler code. You will see exactly what happens,

Comment: @PinkTurtle So that means "yes" to the question I asked ?

Comment: Yes, a copy constructor is invoked.

Comment: Since you are passing by value to the function, it'll create a copy of them. For small types (like fundamentals) this is totally fine. But for objects with expensive copy, pass them by const reference (`const T& x`) or reference (`T& x`) if the function modifies that value.

Comment: Regarding the question about copy-constructor, that really depends on the types. Primitive types (like `int`, `double` or `char*`) doesn't have copy-constructors. Such types still relies on [copy-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) though.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  So you mean that , the initialisation always happens like `T1 x = a;  ` where T1 can be int ,char,bool,vector ,any class object ,etc .  Right ?

Comment: @dd3012 what else could it be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the copy constructor invoked and then initialization happens like `T1 x = a; T2 y = b; T3 z = c;`

Yes, it happens exactly like this. Which, given the amount of different kinds of initializations in C++, is an impressive guess.

It's called *copy-initialization*: (which in general doesn't necessarily imply that a copy constructor is called)

> [`[dcl.init.general]/14`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#14)
>
> The initialization that occurs in the `=` form of a brace-or-equal-initializer or condition ([stmt.select]), as well as in argument passing, function return, throwing an exception ([except.throw]), handling an exception ([except.handle]), and aggregate member initialization ([dcl.init.aggr]), is called copy-initialization.

*"the `=` form of a brace-or-equal-initializer"* refers to `T1 x = a;`, and *"argument passing"* speaks for itself.

Comment: One minor addendum:  the order of the copy is unspecified.  Usually irrelevant.  Until it becomes relevant, like `fun(++a, ++a, ++a)` or `fun(get_int(), get_int(), get_int())`.